# Manage apns notification tokens on client side

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, client, token

When Alice sends Bob a message (while Bob is offline) Bob should be notified. In other implementations the server queries a database for Bobs notification token and sends Bob a notification.

To avoid this extra query I would like to manage the notification tokens on client side (user know  each others token). This would allow Alice to embed Bobs notification token in every message.

Comment: Interesting question. When Alice sends Bob a message, the client of Bob can emit a local notification without using APN. To me, no need to use APN for a local notification. Does this answer your case ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that Bob is offline